# Passing array not pointer to a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, parameters, parameter-passing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the sizeof(a pointer pointing to an array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

I want to pass an array to a function such that if I use the `sizeof` operator on array inside the function body, I should get the actual size of the array and not that of a pointer. For e.g -

```
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};

    printf("Array size = %d\n", sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)); ---> O/P = 40/4 = 10

    func(arr);
}

void func(int arr[])
{
    printf("Array size = %d\n", sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)); --->O/P = 4/4 = 1
}
```

The `printf` statement in the main function prints `10` while the one in `func` prints `1`. Is it possible to do so in `C language`?

**EDIT:** I know other alternatives like `wrapping the array into a struct` etc. Actually, I was trying to solve a problem given on TopCoders site and the requirement of one problem is that I have to write a function(requirement given below). Now I am confused that how I am going to calculate the size of the `int[] donations` array inside `int maxDonations(int[] donations)` function.

```
Definition
Class:  BadNeighbors
Method: maxDonations
Parameters: int[]
Returns:    int
Method signature:   int maxDonations(int[] donations)
(be sure your method is public)
```

If you want, I can post the entire question.

Comment: Dupe, undoubtedly many times, no it's not possible but there are only a million other ways to accomplish what you want.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: I have edited the question to include what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: the syntax of the problem specification clearly show that they are not talking about C

Comment: Did you choose the language on the top right corner of the problem description? I guess you didn't, I remember topcoder's default language is Java.

Answer (score 3):

A cheap way would be to wrap the array into a struct and pass that (or a pointer to the struct).

*However*, I would recommend passing an additional `size_t` argument that specifies the size of the array. This would make your function **more flexible**.

Comment: I would also prefer passing extra argument but the problem statement says that I have to write such function. See the EDIT section, I have posted the requirement also.

Answer (score 0):

In C you cannot pass an array as a parameter to a function directly. You can pass a structure, a pointer or some other numeric value, but not an array.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the constraints in your question, this question is impossible to answer.

In C, `sizeof` is an *operator*, rather than a *function*: you correctly mention this in your question. However, C operators are evaluated at *compile time*, rather than *runtime*, which means that you cannot use `sizeof` in a function in the way you want to - at compile time the compiler cannot tell how `func()` is going to be called.

Looking at the problem as set, I am assuming it is this one:

http://www.cs.duke.edu/csed/algoprobs/neighbors.html

The required method signature on that page is:

```
public int maxDonations(int[] donations)
```

although for some reason, you've omitted the `public` keyword in your question. This keyword indicates that the language in question is *not* C, and [this example solution](http://www.cs.duke.edu/csed/algoprobs/p1solved.html) looks very much as if it is written in Java, in which language this is a non-problem, arrays have a `length` member.

I'd suggest you clarify the requirements for the question from your teacher/website/whatever to check what is really expected.